# UDP broadcast packets in multiple processes bound to one NIC

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp

I am playing with the idea of a .NET peer-to-peer application where one peer advertises its presence on the subnet using UDP packets. Any listening peer would then get enough information from the packet to establish a direct communication channel with to the advertiser using TCP.

It seems that a broadcast packet needs to be directed to specific port number, and, in order to receive packets, the peer needs to bind to that port on IPAddress.Any.

With this design, would it ever be possible to run multiple peers bound to the same NIC? I just get a SocketException "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted", until I add the following line of code:

```
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
```

What are the implications of setting this option?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do that with broadcasts.  On the other hand, it's standard practice with link-local multicasts.  Since the IPv6 multicast API is better designed than the IPv4 API, I recommend using IPv6 link locals — you don't need global IPv6 addresses and routing for that, your application will work on any modern system even without IPv6 connectivity.

First, pick a random IPv6 link-local multicast group, anything in `ff02::/16` will do (see RFC 4291 Section 2.7 for details).  Then, your application should:

1. set `SO_REUSEADDR` on the socket;
2. bind to your chosen port;
3. set `IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP` to 0, `IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS` to 1;
4. subscribe to the multicast group using `IPV6_JOIN_GROUP`;
5. send UDP packets to the multicast group with the interface id of the outgoing interface in `sin6_scope_id`.
6. determine the incoming interface of received packets by checking `sin6_scope_id`.

This is described in detail in RFC 3493 Section 5.2.

Comment: your example still uses UDP and binds to the same port with the ReuseAddress option. Surely the same implications will apply to both of our examples, yet for yours I'd need to additionally learn IPv6 and how multicast works. Or is there something at the adapter level that distinguishes between handling an IPv4 UDP packet and an IPv6 UDP packet?

Comment: With IPv4 broadcasts, you'll need to use different techniques in order to (1) duplicate a received packet to get a copy to each of your processes, and (2) specify the outgoing interface for packets that you send.  The latter is easy, I have no idea how to do the former.  Please add an answer when you find out.